# Why Language Key is displayed like 1 character instead of 2?

Tags: abap

I was trying to learn how to use String Templates and encountering displaying characters.

What I was trying to display is:

> SAP Logon Language Key **EN**

using this line of code:

```
WRITE: |{ text-003 } { sy-langu }|.
```

But instead, it only displays:

> SAP Logon Language Key **E**

it only displays the first character of the language instead of the full 2 letters which are EN

Answer (score 1):

SAP language codes are displayed as two letters, but are internally stored as just one. There are various data-types where the internal and the external representation differ. It's called a conversion-routine and it's defined on the level of the domain in the ABAP dictionary.

If you want to convert to the external representation of a language field, use the function module `CONVERSION_EXIT_ISOLA_OUTPUT`. If you want to do the reverse - convert a UI representation to the database representation - use  `CONVERSION_EXIT_ISOLA_INPUT`.

Comment: not sure how to use that but will give that a try. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To complete Philipp answer, you may also use `WRITE` to convert from database to external representation, it will automatically search the right conversion routine (routine `ISOLA` when the variable is based on a DDIC Data Element which is based on the DDIC Domain `LANGU`, e.g. Data Element `LANGU`, e.g. the system variable `SY-LANGU` which is based on Data Element `LANGU`) - This example works if you log in English:

```
DATA display_language_code TYPE c LENGTH 2.

WRITE sy-langu TO display_language_code.

ASSERT display_language_code = 'EN'.
```